# Show values according to condition in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, function

I'm developing an application in React.JS

I have the array:

```
array =
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "user-1"
                },
                "date": "2021-01-10",
                "hour": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "time": "09:30:00.000"
                },
                "duration": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "time": 30
                },
                "type": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "type-1"
                },
                "prof": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "prof-1"
                },
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "user": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "user-2"
                },
                "date": "2021-01-14",
                "hour": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "time": "10:00:00.000"
                },
                "duration": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "time": 45
                },
                "type": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "type-1"
                },
                "prof": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "prof-1"
                },
            }
        ]
```

and:

```
hour =
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "time": "09:30:00.000"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "time": "10:00:00.000"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "time": "10:30:00.000"
            }
        ]
```

I need to show in a select only the hours that are not available given the equality condition in prof and day.

To try to do this I tried with

```
{
    array.map(item => {
        if (item.prof.id === "1" && item.date === "2021-01-14"){
            return (
                hour.map(elem => {
                    if (elem.id != item.hour.id){
                        return <option value={elem.time.id}>{elem.hour.time}</option>
                    }
                })
            );
        }
    })
}
```

In short I need to show the available hours.

For the example case, it should only show as an option: `09:30:00.000` and `10:30:00.000`, as available hours.

How can I do it, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works perfectly with some little changes:

```
1. === Operation checks type and value, in this case, prof.id has number type and not equal to string 1.
```

```
2. value and text of the options component should be elem.id and elem.time.
```

```
const OptionCreator = () => {
    const profBusyHours = array
      .filter((item) => item.prof.id === 1 && item.date === "2021-01-14")
      .map((item) => item.hour.id);
    return hour
      .filter((elem) => profBusyHours.includes(elem.id) === false)
      .map((elem) => (
        <option key={elem.id} value={elem.id}>
          {elem.time}
        </option>
      ));
  };
```